# What is meant by $A^{+}$ and $A^{-}$ in algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, jordan-algebras

What is meant by $A^{+}$ and $A^{-}$ in algebra? I read it in Jordan Algebra $A^+$

Comment: $A^{+}$ is a linear Jordan algebra under the operation of anti-commutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is an associative algebra over a field of characteristic $\ne2$, it has two related nonassociative algebras, $A^+$ and $A^-$; in the former the multiplication is defined by
$$
x\circ y=\frac{1}{2}(xy+yx)
$$
and it makes $A^+$ into a [Jordan algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_algebra#Special_Jordan_algebras).

In the latter the multiplication is defined by
$$
[xy]=xy-yx
$$
and it makes $A^-$ into a [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Properties).

Note that addition and multiplication by scalars remains the same as in $A$. Notation may vary, though.

Comment: When the characteristic is $2$, then one uses $x\circ y=xy+yx$. Then $[x,y]=xy-yx=xy+yx=x\circ y$ coincide (Seligman, Schafer, Tomber etc.)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I suspected that; I never went beyond the elementary parts of Jordan algebras.